# Howto make Alt + NationalChar work as Alt + US-ASCII?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I want to use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> in shell terminal to be able to kill a word.

The problem is that if I use national characters, namely cyrrilics, after pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CyrChar</kbd> I get a <kbd>CyrChar</kbd> on my tuned xterm and unprintable symbol on gnome terminal.

I know that it is possible to rebind this functionality to some <kbd>CTRL</kbd> combination, say <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> with `bind '"\C-d":shell-kill-word'`, which will work in national mode too, but is there a way to make <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CyrChar</kbd> work similar to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>US-ASCII</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, enter <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CyrChar</kbd> in your shell. You should see something like "^[foo". The "foo" part is what bash sees when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CyrChar</kbd>. Then use `bind '"\efoo":kill-word'` to bind that to the kill-word command. Make sure you replace foo with exactly what follows the `^[`.

For example to bind <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> to kill-word, I would use `bind '"\e[3;3~":kill-word'` since <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ prints `^[[3;3~`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help with my xterm terminal, just because **alt+Cyrchar** = **Cyrchar** there, not **ESC Cyrchar**.

Comment: I've added **XTerm*VT100*metaSendsEscape: True** to my .Xresources and now your solution works for my xterm too!